# How to add a hyperlink to my gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I want to set hyperlink (on image) in my gridview. When user clicks on that hyperlink, a query string should be generated based on selected value of dropdown list. How to set the hyperlink in gridview and how to form query string for that hyperlink?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: is dropdownlist also in GridView?

Comment: @Govind No. Dropdown list is not on the grid view

Comment: and want to same query string for all hyperlinks which are in grid? I think u have to provide more info and aspx markup also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply Cancatinate the value of your dropdown to `NavigateUrl` property of hyperlink

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "PageName.aspx?ID={0}" + "&TID=" + ddl.SelectedValue) %>'
  ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Edit:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="hlEdit" runat="server" 
  PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "PageName.aspx?ID={0}" + "&TID=" + ddl.SelectedValue) %>'
  ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"></asp:ImageButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This probably also works, but will require the dropdowns AutoPostBack property to be set to true, causing the whole page to refresh.
Or?

Comment: This will work 100%, as I have used in many projects, but it will required AutoPost= true to dropdown.

Comment: .Thanks but my requirement is changed now. I have to use image button on the grid and on button click it should get the id from the grid view but I dont know how to get it on button click event. Can u please guide me???

Comment: You can use ImageButton in the same way, you can use PostBackURL property of imageButton instead Navigate URL property of Hyperlink.  Check my edit part.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need javascript for this.

- Add an 'onclick' attribute to your images
- In the onclick handler, you retrieve the dropdownlist value and compose your query
- Set the composed url to the href of your link

Some more detailed information would be useful to be able to provide you with some code..
Are you using an asp HyperLink, ImageButton, ...?
You could for example use the [OnClientClick property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx) in case you would be using an ImageButton.